# Can I digitally buy and download the first Diablo game?

Tags: diablo

Does Blizzard allow people to buy and download the first diablo game online? Or do I need to purchase a physical copy?

Comment: I'm voting to close again because abandonware doesn't give any additional rights to downloading games you have not purchased. Blizzard still owns the IP, and downloading it is still piracy. Whether Blizzard is currently, or will in the future, sell the game is immaterial. Its theirs.

Comment: @Frank True, not sure what the site's policy on abandonware is. I'm nearly certain that StackOverflow will have one, though Arqade might not. We'll see!

Comment: A discussion exists on meta: [Should we allow links to "abandonware" game sites?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The original Diablo game is now available digitaly on GOG, DRM-free and supported on Windows 7, 8, and 10.

https://www.gog.com/game/diablo

You can try [searching on Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B00001IVBL) for either the PC or PlayStation physical copy. If not, look for other releases or bundle. In 1998 there was a re-release bundle called *Diablo + Hellfire*. Blizzard also released a *Game of the Year Collection* in 1998 that contains the original Diablo. The *Blizzard Anthology*, released in 2000, also contains the original Diablo game. The *Diablo Gift Pack* contained the first two Diablo games but no expansions. In 2001, a *Diablo: Battle Chest* was available which contained the original Diablo, Diablo II, and the Lord of Destruction expansion.

Diablo II, however, is still available from [Blizzard's online store](https://us.shop.battle.net/en-us/product/diablo-ii). The original Diablo II game, Lord of Destruction expansion, and the Diablo II Battle Chest (which includes the Diablo II, its expansion, and strategy guides for each) are all there. However, the Battle Chest for Diablo II does not include the original Diablo game, but [Diablo II](https://us.shop.battle.net/en-gb/product/diablo-ii) and [its expansion](https://us.shop.battle.net/en-gb/product/diablo-ii-lord-of-destruction) are available for digital download.

Answer (score 13):

Situation changed just a few days ago.
gog.com offers it now.
https://www.gog.com/game/diablo

Answer (score 5):

The Diablo 2 Battle Chest comes with Diablo 1 game.

Comment: Only the original release of the Diablo Battle Chest comes with the original Diablo. The newer version, which is easier to find, only comes with D2, LoD, and a strategy guide.

Comment: Correction to the - "The Diablo 2 Battle Chest comes with Diablo 1 game." The picture shows that it does before u click the page on the store. However once u click it it shows the diablo 2 battle chest w/o diablo 1

Answer (score 1):

Diablo 1 is now treated as abandonware and can be downloaded online from archive.org.

1. First, download the game [here](https://archive.org/details/Diablo_1996_Blizzard). You can mount this .iso file (right click --> Mount on Windows 10, slightly harder before), and then install Diablo by launching AUTORUN.EXE from the newly mounted Diablo drive.
2. Then, download the 1.09 patch from [here](http://ftp.blizzard.com/pub/diablo/patches/pc/drtl109.exe) to the same folder that you installed Diablo, and launch it in order to update the game. This is the only official patch from Blizzard you'll need.
3. Finally, install the third party patch from [here](http://www.strangebytes.com/index.php/projects/1-diablo-1-windows-7-vista-patch) as well, which fixes a lot of startup and graphical issues and allows you to play at various resolutions, in windowed mode, and etc.

If you want to play with friends, you can utilize GameRanger or Hamachi to play multiplayer games on simulated local networks nowadays, despite Battle.net discontinuing support for the game early in 2018.

Comment: Abandonware is not technically legal to download. There is no LEGAL means of obtaining the game from a download. Look for it in shops. (I still see copies on Game racks in discount stores)

Comment: @Stese We do make an exception for abandon ware: https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/266/should-we-allow-links-to-abandonware-game-sites

Comment: an exception or not, it's misleading to state that abandonware is 'freely downloadable' I've made a comment on that question with that intent.

Comment: @Stese Free as in beer, not as in speech. :D